# Calculate weekdays with algorithm python

Tags: python, dayofweek, leap-year

I´m writing a program that asks the user a date (day, month and year) and you get as answer the day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, etc.). According to his Algorithm:
https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algoritmia/Algoritmo_para_calcular_el_d%C3%ADa_de_la_semana
I´m getting this error:

File "C:/Users/USUARIO/Documents/Programación/Desafio 4/Waldo Muñoz desafio 4/Dia de la semana55.py", line 64, in 
    Algoritmo = ((year - 1) % 7 + ((year - 1) / 4 - 3 * ((year - 1) / 100 + 1) / 4) % 7 + month + day % 7) % 7

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

This is what I have so far:

```
day = int(input("Day of the month (number): "))
month = input("Name of the month: ")
month = month.lower()
year = int(input("The year is (numbers): "))

#In order to calculate the day of the week (Monday, ,Tuestday,etc)
#There are two cases: Leap year and non-leap.
if month == "january":
    month = 0
elif month == "february":
    month = 3
#These two months have equal module in leap year and non-leap.

elif month == "march":
    month = 3 #non-leap
    if(year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)): #condition to be leap
        month = 4
elif month == "april":
    month = 6
    if(year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)):
        month = 0
elif month == "may":
    month = 1
    if(year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)):
        month = 2
elif month == "june":
    month = 4
    if(year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)):
        month = 5
elif month == "july":
    month = 6
    if(year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)):
        month = 0
elif month == "august":
    month = 2
    if(year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)):
        month = 3
elif month == "september":
    month = 5
    if(year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)):
        month = 6
elif month == "october":
    month = 0
    if(year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)):
        month = 1
elif month == "november":
    month = 3
    if(year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)):
        month = 4
elif month == "december":
    month = 5
    if(year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)):
        month = 6
else:
    print("Please, write the date with the correct format.")

Algoritmo = int((year - 1) % 7 + ((year - 1) / 4 - 3 * ((year - 1) / 100 + 1) / 4) % 7 + month + day % 7) % 7
#Algorithm to calculate day of the week

if Algoritmo == 0:
    print ("Monday")
elif Algoritmo == 1:
    print ("Tuesday")
elif Algoritmo == 2:
    print ("Wednesday")
elif Algoritmo == 3:
    print ("Thursday")
elif Algoritmo == 4:
    print ("Friday")
elif Algoritmo == 5:
    print ("Saturday")
elif Algoritmo == 6:
    print ("Sunday")
```

P.S.: I am a native spanish speaker, I'm sorry if there are mistakes...

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry... I´m getting this:

  File "C:/Users/USUARIO/Documents/Programación/Desafio 4/Waldo Muñoz desafio 4/Dia de la semana55.py", line 64, in <module>
    Algoritmo = ((year - 1) % 7 + ((year - 1) / 4 - 3 * ((year - 1) / 100 + 1) / 4) % 7 + month + day % 7) % 7

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: You are missing a quotation mark @ `if month == january":`

Comment: Corrected! (mistake done while translating to english)... I still having the same error

Comment: What is your input when you get this error ?

Comment: Day of the month (number): 25

   Name of the month: october

   The year is (numbers): 2016
   Please, write the date with the correct format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is most likely when you misspelled a month, as you don't trow a error or ask for a correction or otherwise stop the code, it remain as a string which cause the error you see

for instance

```
>>> test()
Day of the month (number): 25
Name of the month: october
The year is (numbers): 2016
Tuesday
>>> test()
Day of the month (number): 25
Name of the month: octubre
The year is (numbers): 2016
Please, write the date with the correct format.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    test()
  File "C:\Users\David\Documents\Python Scripts\stackoverflow_test.py", line 67, in test
    Algoritmo = int((year - 1) % 7 + ((year - 1) / 4 - 3 * ((year - 1) / 100 + 1) / 4) % 7 + month + day % 7) % 7
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
>>>
```

you need to make sure that a correct month is introduced by the user, for that effect you can do something like this

```
months = {"january","february",...}#put all the month here
def ask_month():
    result=""
    while result not in months:
        result = input("Name of the month: ").lower()
    return result
```

also you repeat this too much

```
(year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0))
```

make a new variable which hold that value, and use that instead.

Also that long chain of if-elif can be reduced to a few lines by making a list with the days and indexing it by the result of the calculation like for example

```
days_names=["Monday", "Tuesday", ... ]
print( days_names[Algoritmo] )
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips!